# Node.js, Vue.js, read 'HTTP: Accept-Language' set 'import' then serve the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, import, internationalization

I'm setting a vue.js app with i18n, so I have multiple static translation files for different langues, and tow css files one ltr and the other rtl.

For now I'm setting 'en' as default lang and ltr as default css, serve them, then check the user locales and resend the right files with dynamic import, depending on the user preferred lang.

I've searched a lot, but can't find a way to read the 'HTTP: Accept-Language' set the 'import' then serve the app with the right files from the beginning.

I know vue.js is a frontend framework but it's served from a node.js server, so there must be a way.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert here, but the only correct long-term solution I see is to do server-side rendering, although this requires some work.

As a short-term solution, you could also build all the different versions of your app and serve the correct one, but this is not a very scalable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes server-side rendering is a solution, but I don't really need it, and rebuilding all my app to be serve-side rendered just to overcome this problem is an overkill.

For the short-term solution, even if a do so, I won't be able to know which version to send, since I have no idea how to get the user agent before the initial rendering.

Comment: You have this information in the request `req.headers['user-agent']`

Comment: "This works if page is dynamically rendered by the server, for example by a PHP script" ... do you have any idea how we can inject those scripts and get the same result with a webpack server running on node.js ... for the moment I'll give the req.headers['user-agent'] a try and see if I can get the user agent before the initial rendering (I think main.js is executed only on client side). I'll give you the feedback ... thanks again

Comment: Because of Babel transpiler there is no way to get any information about the browser before the application run on the client side (at least that's what I'v learned so far) ... I'll just keep my configuration as it is ... thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `accepted language` by getting the header on the `nodejs` part.

The desired header is `req.headers["accept-language"]`.

Then you need to pass this information on the `vue` side. Depending on how you integrate `vue` there are different paths to be taken.

- If you are using a template to include `vue` (pug for instance) you can pass the language as a template variable and include different `css` files depending on the desired language.
- If you are including `vue` using `imports` then you can do something like this:

  - create a module that exports a variable for the language and set the variable to the value you get from the header
  - on the `Vue` side import the module and import css based on the value you just set

Comment: What you're suggesting is exactly what I'm doing right now, 1_ rendering the app 2_ checking the user preference on the client side then 3_ sending the right files ... What I want is 1_ reading the "accept-language" 2_ setting the right files before the initial rendering any thing on client side ... From what I've learned so far, there is no way to get any feedback from the client before the app run on the browser, it seem to be impossible because of Babel transpiler ... I guess I'm 
stuck with this configuration ... Thanks for the response

Comment: I’m not suggesting that. The flow I’m suggesting is the following: 1. Check the language on the server side (nodejs), 2. Render the app taking into account the language, again this is happening on the server side one both flows (generating the vue app using a template or including the app via imports)

Comment: Well I can't do so, as far as I know,  there is no way to get the user browser info before the rendering of the app on the browser or even to set set a dynamic "import"  since it has to be hard coded ... all the vue i18n related libraries are setting a default language and there no mention of a "Read header before rendering" any where ... if you have any idea please show me ... I'm using vue.js on node.js installed with vue cli 3 scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but......

You can use :

```
navigator.language
```

I returns exactly what you want.

Besides that, you can use:

```
navigator.languages
```

It returns an array with all browser accepted langs. In my case:

```
[ "pt-BR", "pt", "en-US", "en" ]
```

A complete tutorial (using n18i and vuex) can be found here:

https://itnext.io/setting-language-with-i18n-by-os-language-in-vue-router-vuex-e42c9318c9ec

HTH